# WebStorm: continue merge with generated commit message after resolving conflicts

Tags: git, intellij-idea, merge, webstorm, commit-message

1. I tried to merge one branch with my current branch and got some conflicts.
2. I manually resolved them and clicked apply.
3. WebStorm tried to continue merge but failed because of my pre-commit hooks, which gave me some linting errors.
4. I manually fixed these errors.
5. Now I want to continue my merge, but I haven't found such an option in WebStorm.

I can simply run git commit in WebStorm, but it won't give me this pretty commit message like "Merge remote tracking branch bla bla... Conflicts: bla bla. Instead, it will paste in the commit message I used in my previous successful commit.

I can also run git commit via terminal and it will restore that commit message. But how can I do so in WebStorm UI?

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be that there are other commit message providers (e.g. some task server, or a message saved to the description of changelist, etc), they can overwrite the merge commit message.

So make sure the commit message is not coming from somewhere else. If it is some older commit message, but always the same, check Edit the Default changelist and check if there is something in the Description (Right click on changelist | Edit Changelist).

Comment: I haven't found anything like that and thus I found out that simply running git merge --continue or git commit in the command line brings me the commit message I need.

Answer (score 0):

Select "Amend" before committing - it will fill the message with the merging message